# Is it possible to find what caused a window to deactivate?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, window

In my application, I have a window open. I click a menu item. The code for the window deactivated event is:

```
private void HostWindow_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
       // Can we check here which control is clicked
     }
```

I need to check which menuitem is clicked before I execute the code inside the deactivated event. Any way of doing that?

Comment: Doesn't `e.Source` or `e.OriginalSource` return the item that initiated the event?

Comment: @Rachel - There is no e.Source or e.OriginalSource for window deactivated event